# ViewModel values are always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I've followed some tutorials and I've also scoured StackOverflow but I'm still coming up at a dead end.

Basically, I'm trying to submit a form in MVC 5 (new to MVC, used WebForms heavily though). So here are my components -

**Controller (./Controllers/AccountController.cs)**

```
using BitHost.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BitHost.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(UserAccount model)
        {
            string sEmailAddress = model.EmailAddress;
            string sPassword = model.Password;
            bool bAgreedToTerms = model.AgreedToTerms;

            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel (./Models/AccountModel.cs)**

```
namespace BitHost.Models
{
    public class UserAccount
    {
        public string EmailAddress;
        public string Password;
        public bool AgreedToTerms;
    }
}
```

**View (./Views/Account/Register.cshtml)**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

@model BitHost.Models.UserAccount

<div class="row">
    <h2>Create a new account</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { Class = "form-control", Placeholder = "Email Address" })
        </div><br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { Class = "form-control", Type = "password", Placeholder = "Password" })
        </div><br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Verify Password" />
        </div><br />
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AgreedToTerms, new { Class = "form-control" })
        </div><br />

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
    }
</div>
```

After clicking on "Submit" on the registration form, I do get taken to the [HttpPost] action to create the account, however the variables gathered from the model all contain null values.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's posting null values, but you will want to change your htmlAttributes parameters to lowercase, e.g. `new { @class = "form-control", type = "password", placeholder = "Password" }`

Comment: possible posting null values because in your controller you are not saving anything? you are initializing and then immediately saying `return Redirect`.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles his action methods can be named the same because his first `Register ActionResult` is `HttpGet` and the other `Register ActionResult` is `HttpPost`.

Comment: are you getting the results that you are expecting when debugging?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid my bad! I will remove the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UserAccount is not correct. edit it like this

[image: UserAccount]

Comment: I didn't even think about the `get` and `set` accessors.  solid pick up

Comment: Yep. Good catch. I'm surprised how often I see this done, but it still never occurs to me to look for it. I think I'm so used to seeing properties, my brain just subs in the `{ get; set; }` even though they aren't there.

Comment: @MrDKOz: What you have currently are called "fields", a "property" has a getter and setter, even if they're just auto-implemented. Only properties are eligible to be bound to.

Comment: This worked a treat thank you! Also thank you @Chris Pratt for the explanation.